# Package: get is not installed in this application on VS Code

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using the get_cli for developing the flutter app. I have created 2 modules with the command `get create page:modulename`. But after I formatted the `pubspec.yaml` , it shows the following error on using the command `get create page:modulename`.

> Package: get is not installed in this application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the yaml formatter should be specified with tab size 2 in settings.json

```
 "[yaml]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
 }
```